# Can I render a react component from programmatically created JSX?

Tags: reactjs

So I am working on a small web app where the user enters some markdown with JSX style parameters, and that markdown is rendered with the parameters filled in using some values.

Since I'm already using react, it would be super nice to use react-style templating to generate the final HTML.  I.e. something like:

```
render: function() {

    var markdownString = "#Hello {name}!"
    var myParams = { name: "Markdown" }
    var renderedMarkdown = renderMarkdown(markdownString) //value is <h1>Hello {name}!</h1>

    return(  
        renderJSX(renderedMarkdown, myParams) //renders <h1>Hello Markdown!</h1>
    )

}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Try and put {} around renderJSX like `return(  
        {renderJSX(renderedMarkdown, myParams)} //renders <h1>Hello Markdown!</h1>
    )`

Comment: renderJSX is just a function I made up.  My question is whether something like that exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`as explained in the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html).

Something like this:

```
render: function() {

    var markdownString = "#Hello {name}!"
    var myParams = { name: "Markdown" }
    var renderedMarkdown = {
        __html: renderMarkdown(markdownString)
    }

    return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={renderedMarkdown} />;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really help.  I want to be able to set parameters within the rendered markdown.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood your intent. Surely replacing the parameters is just string substitution?

Comment: Yeah sure it's possible to do it this way.  I am using nested objects for some of the parameters, so I was hoping to leverage the templating that's already built into react/JSX if that functionality is exposed.